# How add color to the background when I clip the background image to the text?

Tags: css

My background image is a picture, I clip that to the text. But I don't want the background now to be white. So how can I change it to a different color?

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/
.item{
  font-size:250px;
}
.box{
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg') repeat;
  color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

[My project on Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/yoMyjG?editors=1100)

I found this technique [here](http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a background-color to the html & body in your CSS, like this:

```
html, body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here's the full code snippet, where you can see the result:

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/
.item{
  font-size:250px;
}
.box{
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg') repeat;
  color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it work like that? Adding the background color to the html but not the box class.

Comment: Adding the background color to the box class doesn't work because setting the `-webkit-background-clip` property to `text`clips the background property to the text, so the `background` and `background-color` properties in the box class only apply to the text in the box class, not the full area of the div. This is the reason why the "NYC" text has a fancy background but the entire div doesn't, as it is from the supplied url from the `background` property with the background clipped to the text.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set a background color as a fall-back default.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
/*Centering*/
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:yellow; /* Default background color */
}
.box{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
/*Clip text*/
.item{
  font-size:250px;
}
.box{
  background: url('https://media.timeout.com/images/103444978/image.jpg') repeat;
  color:#21537a;/*text color for nonwebkit*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
  
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='item'>NYC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout can give an ":after" content to the clipped element, and set its background color as needed, and set the "z-index" lower. It worked for me. I hope it will help, check the link below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Clipped text background</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
.magazin-hero-title {
    font-size: 10rem;
    font-size: 12vw;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/09/19/12/13/flowers-8262456_1280.jpg) fixed center / cover no-repeat;
    color: #de466c;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0px;
    font-family: fantasy;
    letter-spacing: -0px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-right: 26px;
    height: 60vh;
}

.magazin-hero-title:after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(72, 60, 70);
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(72, 60, 70, 1) 47%, rgba(128, 108, 125, .25) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row shadow">
    <section class="magazin-hero-title position-relative w-100" style="">
      SOMETHING<br>TITLE
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="p-5 my5">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Non laudantium nam, accusamus molestiae doloremque vero voluptatem tempora similique, mollitia, porro quo. Iure voluptatibus quos consequatur numquam corrupti distinctio enim porro!</p>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Check it [HERE!](https://codepen.io/imitax/pen/XWoybPa)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).